# No keyboard and Mouse when using qemu to emulate raspiberry3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, keyboard, mouse, qemu

I have no keybord and mouse responding when i try emulates Raspberry Pi3 on Ubuntu with qemu. This is my call:

> qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8
> console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
> rootdelay=1" -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb -sd 2023.img -kernel kernel8.img
> -m 1G -smp 4 -usb -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd

Everything runs fine, except i can't use mouse and keyboard

my qemu-system-aarch64 version is:

> QEMU emulator version 7.0.50 (v7.0.0-2530-g8482ab545e) Copyright (c)
> 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

I running on **Ubuntu 18.04**

Any ideias of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found what was going on. During RaspiOS boot messages i saw a message about some kernel issue. So, i ended founding that i was using a kernel8.img file different from what it should be(an old version). The right file should be inside the RaspiOS image file. So what i did:

```
#this way, you will see the partitions inside img. You should pay 
#attention to the start number of first partition(that is the
#boot partition of .img file)
fdisk -l RaspiOS.img

#you must multiply this number by 512
losetup -o $[ 8192 * 512 ] /dev/loop30 RaspiOS.img

#now, you must mount this partition to some folder
mkdir /mnt/raspi    
mount /dev/loop30 /mnt/raspi

#finally, you shoud copy kernel8.img to your host folder
cp /mnt/raspi/kernel8.img .

#and end all this
umount /mnt/raspi    
losetup -d /dev/loop30    
rmdir /mnt/raspi
```

So, this way i got the right kernel8.img version. I also grab the .dtb files too.

Hope this info can help.